# How does NAT table response when there are no open ports?

Tags: router, nat, network

I'll be glad to hear what really happens if the router has no open ports, for example if there is a big network and every computer sent a lot of requests and the server is slow so the table's ports are waiting to the response to get freed, but it's not happening. Is there any queue for rescue(for ports or something)? Any work that the table/router is doing if the situation occurs ?

Comment: You question is confusing. What does a server have to do with this? If a router is performing NAT for some hosts, and the translation table for one of the protocols is full, then traffic for that protocol would normally be dropped, and there may be an ICMP message sent back to the source host.

Comment: @Ron my question is: what does the router do, if there are no open ports - for example if there are plenty of computers that use a little router (big amount of ips but the network has one NAT table) what would do the router if there no open ports to fill in the table?

Comment: If the table holds 99 entries, then the 100th connection would fail. Go ask early Uverse customers how it works. (hint: the RG tends to crash)

Comment: "_but the network has one NAT table_" There is one NAT table per protocol (UDP, TCP, and ICMP). UDP NAT uses UDP ports, TCP NAT uses TCP ports, and ICMP NAT uses ICMP query IDs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a NAT table in a router is full (out of memory, all available entries for the particular protocol are in use, etc.), then any subsequent translations will fail (the packets will be dropped). The router may (or may not) send an ICMP error message to the source host.

This situation may not arise because you may run into a bandwidth limitation before you could fill the NAT table.

---

Remember that [Network Engineering](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/) is for questions about business-grade equipment, which *should* gracefully handle this situation, but consumer-grade devices (off-topic here) may completely fail.

Comment: Grace, like beauty, is in the eye of the beholder.

Answer (score 1):

Although most NAT routers don't do this, each port (for each protocol) could be used for multiple destinations - each socket is defined by source IP:source port *and* destination IP:destination port.

If many clients connect to the very same server & service = the destination IP:destination port is the same, each sockets requires a different source port - alternatively, a different source IP can also differentiate the socket. This is why larger networks usually use a *source IP pool* for NAT.

However, if the ports or soure IPs are exhausted, the router has no other choice than dropping or rejecting the connection.

Thank God, this NAT kludge has an end with IPv6...

Comment: Sadly I think there will still be significant v4-only networks for the forseeable future.